# find next element by class (may not be a sibling) jquery

Tags: jquery

jquery 3.3.1

I have the following html:

```
    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="first">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="first" field="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control validate" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <label for="mi">Middle Initial:</label>
                        <input type="mi" field="MI" type="text" class="form-control input-sm validate" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="last" field="LastName" type="text" class="form-control validate" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <label for="address">Address:</label>
                            <input type="address" field="Address" type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate" />
                    </div>
```

When i focus into an input field with class validate, I want to find the next field with the class validate. It will not be a sibling of the current elelemnt.

This is my jquery code:

```
  $('.validate').focus(function (e) {
            let ele = $(this).parent().next('.form-group').find('.validate');
            let attr = ele.attr('field');
            console.log('next: ' + attr);

        });
```

If the next element with class validate appears after i do clearfix:

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

my element is undefined in my jquery code. So when i tab out of the input LastName, the next element i want is Address but i cant find it with the above code. If the next element with class validate is directly after the current element without clearfix, it works:

```
   <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <label for="mi">Middle Initial:</label>
                    <input type="mi" field="MI" type="text" class="form-control input-sm validate" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="last" field="LastName" type="text" class="form-control validate" />
                </div>
```

I tab out of Firstname and i can find input  Middle Initial just fine. How do i get the the next element with class validate regardless of where it is located on the DOM tree?

Thanks

Comment: @TylerRoper - i looked at that and that's where i got the code i posted. just changed class names. it didn't work

Comment: It does work: https://jsfiddle.net/a7sej412/. Also note that you've duplicated some `type` attributes in your HTML. I removed those from the fiddle

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it element agnostic, you can use the `index()` method to get the index of the element within all the elements with the same class, and then just advance it.

```js
var $allValidateElements = $('.validate').on('focus', function(e){
  var myIndex = $allValidateElements.index(e.target);
  var nextIndex = ++myIndex;
  
  $allValidateElements.removeClass('red-border');
  $allValidateElements.eq(nextIndex).addClass('red-border');
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label for="first">First Name:</label>
  <input type="first" field="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control validate" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
  <label for="mi">Middle Initial:</label>
  <input type="mi" field="MI" type="text" class="form-control input-sm validate" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="last" field="LastName" type="text" class="form-control validate" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <input type="address" field="Address" type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate" />
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. I tweaked my code to output what i needed. Thanks a ton :)